# Trignometry Integration Problem with $\cos^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on the following problem:

$$\int_0^\pi\left(1-\cos^2x\right)^{0.5}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

The first step I took was to break down $\cos^2(x)$ into $0.5(1+\cos(2x))^{0.5}$  but I don't know what to do past this point.

A step through would be greatly appreciated

Comment: $$1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$$

Comment: Your differential $\mathrm dx$ is missing. You don't integrate a mere function -- you integrate the differential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply :

$$\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sqrt{\sin^2x}=\vert\sin x\vert=\sin x$$ whenever $x\in[0,π].$

Comment: @DonThousand  Next time, don't answer in a comment, maybe, and post an answer, rather than trying to take credit for the answer from another user who does post an answer??

Answer (score 0):

Note thar $x^{1/2}=\pm \sqrt{x}, if x>0.$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} (1-\cos^2 x)^{1/2}=\int_{0}^{\pi} \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}~dx= \int_{0}^{\pi} \pm \sin x dx=\mp \cos x|_{0}^{\pi}=
\mp [-1-1]=\pm 2.$$

Comment: This is not correct. Roots are positive (at least by convention)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have edited it now, thanks.

Comment: It's still wrong. It's either always positive or always negative. $\sin$ oscillates.

Comment: $\sin x$ does not change sign in $[o,\pi]$.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying attention to the range. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Dr Ahmed's answer is good, but there's an additional detail I think you might want to heed for future problems.

Usually, when we take the square root of a squared expression, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So in the third step of Dr Ahmed's solution we should have $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\sin^2(x)} dx=\int_0^\pi |\sin(x)| dx$.

Since $\sin(x)$ is positive for all $x\in[0,\pi]$, we can remove the absolute value bars and just have $$\int_0^\pi |\sin(x)|dx=\int_0^\pi \sin(x) dx=2.$$

---

If the integral's lower bound covered a region where $\sin(x)$ could yield negative values, then we'd need to split the integral appropriately. For instance:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\sin(x)|=\int_{-\pi}^{0}-\sin(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)dx.$$

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that he changed his answer